# How do i stop running webserver on my ubuntu?

Tags: apache2, php, xampp

i've been using xampp as my local host webserver for a while untill suddenly i tried to start it today for some tutorial it says "failed to start Apache...another web server is already running,, any help please?

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't already launched xampp and Apache yet, say, automatically at boot?

Answer (score 0):

Read `man lsof`. This `lsof` invocation will show you which process has IPv4 TCP port 80 open:

```
sudo lsof -i4TCP@localhost:80
```

or

```
sudo netstat -nape --inet
```

Read `man netstat`

Comment: i get nothing..

Comment: That response gives me no information. Which command(s) did you type? Did you type them correctly? What results did the commands give? If you care so little about helping me help you, why should I?